# JOIN and SELECT in SELECT issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 3 tables in which there are about 70 columns combined.

What I am trying to do is select everything from 1 and 2 but then there are certain conditions to get first and last score and those are in third table.

```
SELECT 
    ID, NAME, TIME, ROUNDS
    (SELECT SCORE
     FROM TABLE2 TAB2
     JOIN TABLE3 TAB3 ON TAB2.ID = TAB3.ID
     WHERE PARAMETER1 = 9 AND PARAMETER2 = 21) AS FIRST,
    (SELECT SCORE
     FROM TABLE2 TAB2
     JOIN TABLE3 TAB3 ON TAB2.ID = TAB3.ID
     WHERE PARAMETER1 = 15 AND PARAMETER2 = 2) AS LAST
FROM 
    TABLE1 TAB1
JOIN 
    TABLE2 TAB2 ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID
GROUP BY 
    ID, NAME, TIME, ROUNDS
```

I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I also tried to do the joins at the end and I do get a result but it is wrong

```
SELECT 
    ID, NAME, TIME, ROUNDS
    (SELECT SCORE
     WHERE PARAMETER1 = 9 AND PARAMETER2 = 21) AS FIRST,
    (SELECT SCORE
     WHERE PARAMETER1 = 15 AND PARAMETER2 = 2) AS LAST
FROM 
    TABLE1 TAB1
JOIN 
    TABLE2 TAB2 ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID
JOIN 
    TABLE3 TAB3 ON TAB2.ID = TAB3.ID
```

I get incorrect data because I cannot group it since it wants me to group parameters as well

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
> Column 'PARAMETER1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong so is there any way you guys can help ?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Your subqueries aren't correlated, so (as the error tells you) they return multiple rows. Correlate them.

Comment: GROUP BY without any aggregate functions is (almost) always wrong.

Comment: Also reusing an alias when within the same query, let alone shared scopes, is a poor idea; in the same query is confusing enough, but for the latter it can generate unexpected behaviour. I *suspect* you think you have 1 instance of the table `TABLE2` (aliased as `TAB2`) in your first query. You would be wrong; there are 3.

Comment: Additionally you neglect to correlate the table aliases with columns so it's  impossible to be sure which column belongs to which table.

Comment: As I noted in my rollback *"Do not edit your question after you have received answers to a new/different question; if your goal posts have moved, or you asked the wrong question, ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need to correlate your subqueries, and I suspect that you *think* that all 3 references to `TABLE2 TAB2` are the same instance of said object. This is a flawed understanding. Each time you reference an object it is a new "instance" of it.

As such what you likely want is this:

```sql
SELECT TAB1.ID,
       TAB1.NAME,
       TAB2.TIME,
       TAB2.ROUNDS,
       (SELECT TAB3.SCORE
        FROM dbo.TABLE3 TAB3 
        WHERE TAB3.ID = TAB2.ID
          AND TAB3.PARAMETER1 = 9
          AND TAB3.PARAMETER2 = 21) AS FIRST,
       (SELECT TAB3.SCORE
        FROM dbo.TABLE3 TAB3 
        WHERE TAB3.ID = TAB2.ID
          AND TAB3.PARAMETER1 = 15
          AND TAB3.PARAMETER2 = 2) AS LAST
FROM dbo.TABLE1 TAB1
     JOIN dbo.TABLE2 TAB2 ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID;
```

Or perhaps you would be better off with conditional aggregation, which would mean 1 scan of the table `dbo.TABLE3`:

```sql
SELECT TAB1.ID,
       TAB1.NAME,
       TAB2.TIME,
       TAB2.ROUNDS,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TAB3.PARAMETER1 = 9 AND TAB3.PARAMETER2 = 21 THEN TAB3.Score END) AS FIRST,
       MAX(CASE WHEN TAB3.PARAMETER1 = 15 AND TAB3.PARAMETER2 = 2 THEN TAB3.Score END) AS FIRST
FROM dbo.TABLE1 TAB1
     JOIN dbo.TABLE2 TAB2 ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID
     JOIN dbo.TABLE3 TAB3 ON TAB2.ID = TAB3.ID
GROUP BY TAB1.ID,
         TAB1.NAME,
         TAB2.TIME,
         TAB2.ROUNDS;
```

*Note that the tables the columns belong to is guessed. If incorrect, you'll need to correct.*

Comment: at the 2nd answer it tells me this :  Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.5' to data type int. And i still dont know what im doing wrong my solution is same as your first answer but it still returns that subquery returns more than 1 value..

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, @BrianOrion ... It was *assumed* that your column(s) `PARAMETER1` and `PARAMETER2` are an `int` (or at least numerical) data type as you compare them to one in your attempt. Clearly at least one of them is not. Either you need to fix your design (as you are storing numerical data as an `(n)varchar`), or change the query to compare to `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems below nested queries return multiple values .

```
    (SELECT SCORE
     WHERE PARAMETER1 = 9 AND PARAMETER2 = 21) AS FIRST
   (SELECT SCORE
     WHERE PARAMETER1 = 15 AND PARAMETER2 = 2) AS LAST
```

You should use top(1) with order by ascending for first and descending for last   column as below.

```
SELECT 
    ID, NAME, TIME, ROUNDS
    (SELECT top(1) SCORE
     WHERE PARAMETER1 = 9 AND PARAMETER2 = 21 order by SCORE asc ) AS FIRST,
    (SELECT top(1) SCORE
     WHERE PARAMETER1 = 15 AND PARAMETER2 = 2 order by SCORE desc ) AS LAST
FROM 
    TABLE1 TAB1
JOIN 
    TABLE2 TAB2 ON TAB1.ID = TAB2.ID
JOIN 
    TABLE3 TAB3 ON TAB2.ID = TAB3.ID
```

I think above query helps you finding error on exact location.

Comment: If i do this all  rows will havethe same first and last...